# How can i change this Oracle SQL to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

The following Oracle SQL is

```
merge into table1 rs 
using table2 ch 
on (rs.id = ch.id) 
when matched then 
    update set rs.column = ch.column 
    where rs.column is not null
```

I want to change this SQL to MySQL. How can i do that?

Comment: INSERT INTO table1 rs SELECT ch.column FROM table2 ch INNER JOIN table1 rs ON rs.id = ch.id where rs.column is not null ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rs.column = ch.column ... or something very close to it

Comment: Have you tried understanding what the above query does and tried converting it ?

Comment: Google mysql merge.

Comment: This command does not insert when there is no match. So, it is, in essence, only an update. Therefore, you should be able to write it as such in mysql.

Answer (score 2):

That merge is only doing an update, not an insert.

So you can use an update statement for it

```
update table1 rs
inner join table2 ch on rs.id = ch.id
set rs.column = ch.column
where rs.column is not null
```

And if you would need an upsert, MySql has an [insert on duplicate key update syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Answer (score 0):

mySQL does not have a "MERGE" statement.
However, there are 3 ways you can achieve this:
1. Using @valicu2000 's solution.
2. Using REPLACE syntax

```
REPLACE into table1 rs(`column`) values(select column from table2 ch) where table1.id=table2.id and table2.column is not null
```

3. Try a transactional update and insert(but, that's gonna be 2 queries)